# How to skip a column while and not copy that column and copy the other columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code here where it works great is doing what I want for my report but the only problem is that I want to exclude one column while copying data from one file to another. my code copies from column A to I but I want to exclude all data from H and probably move the data from I to the H so I don't have a empty column H. hope this make sense any help is appreciated thanks.

```
Sub Distinct()
Const TRNS_START As String = "TRNS"
    Const TRNS_END As String = "ENDTRNS"
    Const COMPANY As String = "Triumph Foods LLC"

    Dim searchRng As Range, copyRngStart As Range, copyRngEnd As Range

    Set searchRng = Worksheets("Information").Range("A1")

    ' Enter/continue loop while A-column is non-empty
    Do While searchRng.Value <> ""

        ' When we encounter the string TRNS in column A and Triumph Foods LLC in column E
        If searchRng.Value = TRNS_START And _
           searchRng.Offset(0, 4).Value = COMPANY Then

            Set copyRngStart = searchRng ' Set the start of the copy area
        End If

        ' When we encounter the string ENDTRNS
        '    (*and had a start cell already*)
        If searchRng.Value = TRNS_END And Not copyRngStart Is Nothing Then

            Set copyRngEnd = searchRng.Offset(-1, 8)

            copyRngEnd.Worksheet.Range(copyRngStart, copyRngEnd).Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets("Display").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            Set copyRngStart = Nothing 'clear the "start" range

        End If

        Set searchRng = searchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Union` to create a non-contiguous range to copy, like this

```
Sub Distinct()
    Const TRNS_START As String = "TRNS"
    Const TRNS_END As String = "ENDTRNS"
    Const COMPANY As String = "Triumph Foods LLC"

    Dim searchRng As Range, copyRngStart As Range, copyRngEnd As Range, copyRng As Range
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet

    Set wsFrom = Worksheets("Information")
    Set searchRng = wsFrom.Range("A1")

    ' Enter/continue loop while A-column is non-empty
    Do While Not IsEmpty(searchRng.Value)    
        ' When we encounter the string TRNS in column A and Triumph Foods LLC in column E
        If searchRng.Value = TRNS_START And _
           searchRng.Offset(0, 4).Value = COMPANY Then

            Set copyRngStart = searchRng ' Set the start of the copy area
        End If

        ' When we encounter the string ENDTRNS
        '    (*and had a start cell already*)
        If searchRng.Value = TRNS_END And Not copyRngStart Is Nothing Then

            Set copyRngEnd = searchRng.Offset(-1, 6) ' A:G

            Set copyRng = wsFrom.Range(copyRngStart, copyRngEnd)
            ' union with I
            Set copyRng = Application.Union(copyRng, copyRng.Columns(1).Offset(, 8))     
            copyRng.Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets("Display").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            Set copyRngStart = Nothing 'clear the "start" range

        End If
        Set searchRng = searchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not much fan of copying using VBA, but prefer to assign the values directly. For your specific issue I suggest breaking the assignation of the values into 2 parts. So in your code when you would be copying the values you would replace your code with:

```
Sheets("Display").Range("A" & (Sheets("Display").Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1) & ":H" & (Rows.Count + 1)).Value2 = Worksheets("Information").Range("A1:G1").Offset(copyRngStart.Row, 0)
Sheets("Display").Range("I" & (Sheets("Display").Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1)).Value2 = Worksheets("Information").Range("H1").Offset(copyRngStart.Row, 0)
```

This will write directly first from A to G and then write I to H.Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without any explanation! Whoever it was!